# `transform` With `vh` Units Acting Weird Inside SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

Why are the `vh` units weird here?  What is the reference for `100vh` here?  (Note that this is not due to the iframe, it works the same on a full screen website.  The fraction of the circle visible seems to depend on the window height, which it shouldn't, since it is moved by the `vh` unit.)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
svg {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<main>
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="transform: translateY(10vh)"/>
</svg>
</main>
```

Comment: What surprises you here? You have a "viewBox="0 0 100 100" and an implicit `width="100%" height="100%"`. The `1vh` will be converted to the SVG's internal coordinate system, where `1` is `1px`, and `1vh` is converted to `Npx` before it's set into that coordinate system.

Comment: OK, thank you, I didn't know that `viewBox` equals viewport here.  But even then, if we set the `svg` height to `100vh`, shouldn't the view box match the viewport?

Comment: No, you'd have to set your `viewBox`'s height so that it matches `1vh` if you want `1vh` to map correctly.

Comment: But according to your logic, it would take `100vh` to be `100px` (from the `viewBox`) but that's also not the case, the `vh` seem to grow even *faster* than the viewport height, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/51fvwynm/54/

Comment: No it's the inverse relationship. `100vh` is first converted to CSS `px` and then passed into the SVG coordinate system which will stretch it to whatever the size of the SVG is rendered at that time. You have to set your SVG's height to `100px` not to `100vh` if you don't want the SVG's scaling to kick in.